# Count sum of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to count the sum of 2 columns from a subset of results, so far I have put this together

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_1 + column_2 >= 3 IN (SELECT id 
                                   FROM table_name 
                                   where id = 16 
                                   AND (name = 'Richard') 
                                   ORDER BY column_3 
                                   DESC LIMIT 10);
```

What I am expecting as output is the number of cases where the sum is `>=3`, so as an example 5

At the moment I get the error

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer >= boolean
```

I feel I am on the wrong path though. How can I construct this query please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving a value for the [IN](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/) statement, which returns a boolean stating if a value is within the results of your SELECT statement

The easiest change to your query for it to work would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name 
WHERE column_1 + column_2 >= 3 
AND id IN(
  SELECT id FROM table_name 
  WHERE id = 16 AND (name = 'Richard')
  ORDER BY column_3 DESC LIMIT 10
);
```

However, the correct approach in case that table_name is actually used twice would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
WHERE id = 16 AND (name = 'Richard')
AND column_1 + column_2 >= 3
ORDER BY column_3 DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you Matias, helped a lot there, can see where I went wrong too, good explanation